# Unable to Launch the Android Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a Hello-Android Application and made all the required configurations as told in the developer.android.com site. When i ran the application the emulator was not launched.

In the console the following message was displayed.

```
"[2011-07-08 10:44:04 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-07-08 10:44:04 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-08 10:44:04 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.HelloAndroid.HelloAndroidActivity activity launch
[2011-07-08 10:44:04 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD'
[2011-07-08 10:44:04 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD'".
```

Then a pop up message came which showed the following.

```
"An Unhandled win32 exception occured in emulator-arm.exe[3656]. 
Just-In_time debugging this exception failed with the following error:
No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging Enabled. 
In Visual Studio,Just-In_time debugging can be enabled from 
Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In_time.

Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' 
for more information."
```

Please help me out so that I can launch the emulator.

Comment: Did you trying starting your AVD via the Android SDK and AVD Manager? If that works and the AVD does start properly, you can try to run your app once the AVD is up and running.

Comment: Can you please explain me clearly what all i should do so that i can run the application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the Android SDK Manager
2. In the SDK Manager, go to the "Virtual devices" page and click "New" to create a new device.
   Make sure you create a "Target" API that is within the range of the API's that your app supports.
3. Once the Android Virtual Device (AVD) is created click "Start" to start it.
4. Wait until the AVD is fully started, then goto Eclipse
5. In Eclipse create a "Run configuration" for your app (if you do not have it already). In the run configuration
   make sure you select the device you've just created.
6. Run your "run configuration".

Comment: Do you know the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few instrucitons before running the Android applicaiton.

1. Make sure when you are launching the emulator for the first time for running this specific app you have not checked  following  check boxes.

   . Launching from snapshots

   because first time you don't have any snapshot existed before as you are running this application for the first time.

   2   Make sure that you have selected small resolution emulator because larger resolutions does not perform good.